# MySQL Join - Query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, relational-database

I have a question about how I would structure a query.

I have 2 tables.

```
Store

 - store_id -- primary key
 - zip_code

Merchandise

 - item_id -- primary key
 - item_name
 - description
 - cost
 - storeID -- foreign key that references the store_id from the store.
```

> I am using InnoDB.

I want the user to be able to input 1-5 choices that are 1 word apiece and it would cross reference the decription and tell me the store that has them both.
For instance, choice 1 = clock, choice 2 = paper, and choice 3 = food.  It would query a result that would give me the stores and items that have items that match the description of them ALL.  For instance, it would return Wal - Mart based on this query because it would be the only store that had an item to match each description.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: At the very least provide (add to your question by using `edit`) your sample data and the desired result.

Comment: you would be better off having three tables. stores. merchandise and store_merchandise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description you could do it like this:

```
select storeid 
  from merchandise
    where description = 'clock' or description = 'paper' or description = 'food'
  group by storeid
  having count(*) = 3;
```

With an example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6c2d/3

But there are far better ways to organise your schema.

**edit**
updated per further requirements in comments:

This query will retrieve the store details for you, as well as limit by zip_code:

```
select storeid, name 
  from merchandise m
    inner join stores s
      on m.storeid = s.store_id
    where (description = 'clock' or description = 'paper' or description = 'food') and zip_code = 3456
  group by storeid
  having count(*) = 3;
```

Updated fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c94dd/1

**edit**
Amended to include possibility of more than one item matching criteria when using `like`

```
  select storeid, name 
  from merchandise m
    inner join stores s
      on m.storeid = s.store_id
    where (description like '%clock%' or description like '%paper%' or description like '%food%') 
  group by storeid
  having count(case when description like '%clock%' then 1 end) >= 1 
    and count(case when description like '%paper%' then 1 end) >= 1 
    and count(case when description like '%food%' then 1 end) >= 1
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54708/5

Comment: That looks like it works great!  Would I not need to join my tables though?

Comment: only if you want other info about your stores.

Comment: But since the storeid is part of my merchandise class and store name is part of the store class, I think I would need that.  And I may pass in an argument for zip code as well that the user inputs.

Comment: If description was many words and I wanted to search for a specific word, I would use description LIKE '%$variable%' instead of description = 'variable' right?

Comment: yes .. but it may require a bit more tweaking because it could possibly match more than one product, and throw the count out. let me know if you want further help with that

Comment: I wish i could give you 100 thumbs up!  Thanks!  Works great on php admin but not on my webpage.  Probably just needs a little formatting.  Thank you!

Comment: the only thing i noticed that I can't get to work is if it has one user choice, lets say clock.  I'm trying to get it to return the store and ALL items that have clock as description.  As of right now, it just shows the first item and that meets the criteria.  Any advice?

Comment: Just run a second query once you get the storeids